# AR Session doesn't reset in Unity while switching between scenes

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, arkit

I'm using the following code to load/unload scene. I've a simple setup of two scenes and I'm switching between two scenes.

```
 public static void GoToScene(string sceneName) {
      SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
 }
```

It works as expected in Unity Editor, However, when I export it for iOS Unity Framework and run the app on phone it doesn't work as expected.

I've also tried the following while switching between scenes:

```
 arSession.Reset();
```

Any solution or ideas to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Found a thread on Unity Forum which is almost similar:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/reset-ar-session.537261/

Comment: You didn’t include the scene. In your build

Comment: I did, I did included both the scenes on the build.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it intended to not reset like mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/issues/312#issuecomment-653250601)?

If you want to reset it you may have to call

```
LoaderUtility.Deinitialize()
LoaderUtility.Initialize()
```

Like what they done in [SceneUtility.cs](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/blob/main/Assets/Scripts/Runtime/SceneUtility.cs)